# Enviar misma accion de mi componente en mi NavBar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Colegas, estoy empezando con REACT tengo hasta el momento un login, donde me envía a un formulario que lo denomino MENU sin embargo continuando investigando, llegué a la parte de creación de mi barra de navegación, en mi MENU, tengo un botón que me cierra la sesión y me envía al login, sin embargo no se como hacer para que esa función de cerrar sesión poderla poner en mi componente NavBar, ya que cerrar sesión está en mi MENU, entonces he leído sobre montón de cosas pero no logra replicarlas hooks, Contex, entre otros.

**MENU.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import tema from '../temaConfig'
import Nav from '../componentes/navBar'


const cookies = new Cookies();

class Menu extends Component {
    cerrarSesion = () => {
        cookies.remove('usuario', { path: "/" });
        window.location.href = "./";
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        if (!cookies.get('usuario')) {
            window.location.href = "./"
        }
    }
    render() {
        

        console.log(cookies.get('usuario'))
        return (
            <ThemeProvider theme={tema}>
                <Nav  />
                    
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => this.cerrarSesion()}>
                    Cerrar Sesion
                </Button>
            </ThemeProvider>





            // <ThemeProvider theme={tema} >
            //     <Nav />
            //     <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => this.cerrarSesion()}>
            //         Cerrar Sesion
            //     </Button>
            //     <div className={clase.offset}>
            //     </div>
            // </ThemeProvider>
        )
    }
}
export default Menu;
```

```
**NAVBAR.jsx**

import React from 'react';
import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography } from '@material-ui/core'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles'
import { IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import MenuRoundedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MenuRounded';



const useStyles = makeStyles(tema => ({
    offset: tema.mixins.toolbar,
    menuButton: {
        marginRight: tema.spacing(4)
    },
    title: {
        flexGrow: 1
    }
}))
const Nav = () => {
    const clases = useStyles()
    return (
        <div>
            <AppBar >
                <Toolbar>
                    <IconButton className={clases.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="menu">
                        <MenuRoundedIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                    <Typography variant='h6' className={clases.title}>
                        MENU PRINCIPAL
                    </Typography>
                    <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" onClick='AQUI NO SE COMO EJECUTAR' >
                        Cerrar Sesion
                    </Button>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
            <div className={clases.offset}>

            </div>

        </div>
    )
}
export default Nav;
```

Comment: A tu `<Nav>` puedes pasarle la función como un `prop` y mandarla a llamar desde donde tu lo necesites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución es pasar la función como un `prop` al componente `Nav`. Para ello, necesitarías hacer lo siguiente en el componente de `Menu`.

```
    <ThemeProvider theme={tema}>
        <Nav cerrarSesion={this.cerrarSesion}/>
            
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => this.cerrarSesion()}>
            Cerrar Sesion
        </Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
```

Y en el componente de `Nav`, en donde necesites llamar la función haces lo siguiente:

```
<Button variant="contained" color="secondary" onClick={() => props.cerrarSesion()}>
Cerrar Sesion
</Button>
```

Comment: Tengo el siguiente error: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined** `<Typography variant='h6' className={clases.title}>
  30 |         MENU PRINCIPAL
  31 |     </Typography>
> 32 |     <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" onClick= {()=> this.props.cerrarSesion} >
     | ^  33 |         Cerrar Sesion
  34 |     </Button>
  35 | </Toolbar>`

Comment: Añade los props a tu componente. `const Nav = (props) => {...}`

Comment: Haber entendería que en mi navBar.jsx quedaría : ` const Nav = (props) => {
    const clases = useStyles() ` .......  ?

Comment: Es correcto, necesitas agregar props en ese paréntesis vacío que tienes.

Comment: Sigo teniendo este error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta. Una disculpa, debes quitar el this, cuando llamas a los props de Nav. Además de añadirlos en el paréntesis vacío de `const Nav = (props)`

Comment: Completamente así fue el caso, muchas gracias Jacobo